# Choosing dropdownlist value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created event for select index changed for dropdownlist like below but the event is not firing.I dont know what is going wrong?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcurrency" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcurrency_SelectedIndexChanged1"   >
                      <asp:ListItem Value="Nrs" >Nrs</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Value="$" >$</asp:ListItem>
                      </asp:DropDownList>
     protected void ddlcurrency_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (ddlcurrency.Items.FindByText("$").Selected == true) //keeping the currency value in session
                {
                    Session["Curr"] = "Dol";

                }
                else
                {
                    Session["Curr"] = "Nrs";
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcurrency" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcurrency_SelectedIndexChanged1"   >
                      <asp:ListItem Value="Nrs" >Nrs</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Value="$" >$</asp:ListItem>
                      </asp:DropDownList>
```

Have you tried setting a break point at the SelectedIndexChaged event of the DDL to check if HITS there?

Comment: No it  doesnot hit in the event.

Comment: when you change the dropdown page is post back ie: page reload or not? And also Check whether the debug is set to false in web.config?
<system.web>
        <compilation
            debug="true"
            ...
        >
        ...
        </compilation>
    </system.web>

Comment: Ok it works now but when I goes to another page the drodpownlist value will be changed as the page will be refresh.

Comment: >>but when I goes to another page the drodpownlist value will be changed as the page will be refresh.
Not understand your question.

Comment: I mean to say my dropdownlist is in master page and when I first select the value in first page then I want to have the same value in other page unless I changed the value.

Comment: You are already using a session ie: Session["Curr"] use that session value in another page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcurrency" runat="server" AutoPostback="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcurrency_SelectedIndexChanged1"   >
                      <asp:ListItem Value="Nrs" >Nrs</asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Value="$" >$</asp:ListItem>
                      </asp:DropDownList>



protected void ddlcurrency_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            if (ddlcurrency.Items.FindByText("$").Selected == true) //keeping the currency value in session
            {
                Session["Curr"] = "Dol";

            }
            else
            {
                Session["Curr"] = "Nrs";
            }

    }
```

Comment: what is the difference in ur answer?

Comment: @See my ediit. Remove ispostback and add AutoPostback=true

Answer (score 0):

**Set autopost back property of dropdown control to true**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcurrency" runat="server" 
 OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcurrency_SelectedIndexChanged1"   AutoPostBack="true" >
```